# "Invalid norm order for matrices" when using np.linalg.norm with the 'nuc' norm

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compute the nuclear norm (trace norm on singular values) of a square matrix A. I have delcared the matrix as an np.array object. When i try to run the following I get an error telling me you cannot use this norm for matrices; but it's a norm for matrices!

```
A = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
Anorm = np.linalg.norm(A, ord='nuc')
```

Comment: It works fine for me with `Anorm = 2.0`.

Comment: Weird, I get the following error message: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 2129, in norm
    raise ValueError("Invalid norm order for matrices.")
ValueError: Invalid norm order for matrices."

Comment: I am using `'1.14.3'` version of NumPy and python version `3.6.5 `. I see you are still using python 2.7

Comment: This is working for me on python 2.7. Also getting 2.0.